# quickest way to convert Sqlite Database to MS - Access (2003/7007) Format

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

what can be the quickest way to convert a sqlite database to MS-access format, give that i dont have the table structure of the database.

my best possible guess is

connect to sqlite db, get table schemas, then duplicate the table data row by row.

i need the quickest way possible.

regards
raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way:

- Install an [ODBC driver for SQLite](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqliteodbc.htm)
- In Access, [create linked tables](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php). You will be given the choice of linking to the table or creating a copy of the table and data in Access.

Comment: any way to do it in c#? actually i have a lot of SQLite database which needs to be converted to MS-access!

Comment: @classic.programmer: there are many ways to do this. You could manipulate Access as a COM object and create the ODBC linked tables through that. You could also just open the SQLite database from C#, go through its tables, use DAO from C# to create the Access database and the new tables in it, then go through the data in each SQLite table and re-create that data in the Access table. In any case, if you want to do it programmatically from C#, it will require some work. Unless someone has already done a tool to do that, there is mo magic bullet I'm afraid.